# ExpressJS route with arrays

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

Using ExpressJS and hbs to route between views on the client side. Also printing data from arrays on the server.

Works fine when sending 2 arrays to the index page.

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.render("index", {array: array, array2: array2});
});
```

Is it possible to send more than one array when routing with id as params?

```
app.get("/index/:id", function(req, res){
  var id = req.params.id;
  res.render('details', array[id]);
});
```

Comment: You mean like `{ array: array[id], array2: array2[id] }`?

Comment: Yes, but that does not work.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Not getting any error, but the data that is printed on the /index/:id page when running res.render('details', array[id]); does not print when using { array: array[id], array2: array2 }.

Comment: what happens if you debug that line of `{ array: array[id], array2: array2[id] }`? If you breakpoint on that line, can you look inside those objects correctly in watch statements?